# How to replace a floor with another floor when hitting a button and that it cost money?

Tags: roblox

I'm making a tycoon and i would like that when people hit a button it changes the floor by paying with their money.

It will be a upgrade for the floor like when they hit the first button they get a better version of their inital floor and then when they press the second button they get again a better version of the second floor.

When they first claim the tycoon this is dirt roads then the Upgrade version 1 is like stone roads and then the upgrade version 2 is like asphalt roads.

I have already one floor and i would like to replace it whith a better one when people hit the button FloorTier2 and then again a better one when they press FloorTier3.

I don't know how to do it. i've made the button and i also made the roads but i need a script that can replace the floor that is linked to the button they have hitted.